Docstring on bottom panel (Shift+Tab 4x) not showing
I recall that Shift+Tab: View the docstring for a function. Hit Shift+Tab three more times to open the docstring in a new pane. Is the Shift+Tab 4x no longer pulling up the docstring on a new bottom panel?
I found reference on this at this website: https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/most-useful-keyboard-shortcuts-for-notebook-lab/18113
Below are my packages and versions:
IPython          : 8.15.0
ipykernel        : 6.28.0
ipywidgets       : 8.1.3
jupyter_client   : 8.6.0
jupyter_core     : 5.7.2
jupyter_server   : 2.14.1
jupyterlab       : 4.2.3
nbclient         : 0.8.0
nbconvert        : not installed
nbformat         : 5.10.4
notebook         : 7.2.1
qtconsole        : 5.5.2
traitlets        : 5.14.3
I've tried to update all the packages to the latest version.
